# Simplifying $\int\cos^2(x)\sin(2x)dx$ via the optimal substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

I was just tutoring and a student's question was: Make a trig substitution to make evaluating $\int \cos^2(x)\sin(2x)dx$ simpler.

So yeah, the question is only asking for what trigonometric substitution do we use to simplify the integral, it's not asking to evaluate the integral.

---

FIRST ATTEMPT:

Using $\sin(2x)=2\cos(x)\sin(x)$ the integral becomes

$$\begin{aligned}&\int\cos^2(x)\sin(2x)dx\\&=\int\cos^2(x)2\cos(x)\sin(x)dx\\&=2\int\cos^3(x)\sin(x)\end{aligned}$$

I thought this was a good answer because if we set $u =\cos^2(x)$, then by the chain rule we get $$du = -2\cos(x)\sin(x)dx$$ and thus  $$\frac{du}{-2\cos(x)\sin(x)}=dx$$

And so

$$\begin{aligned}&\int\cos^2(x)2\cos(x)\sin(x)dx\\&=2\int\cos^3(x)\sin(x)dx\\&=\int\cos^2(x)(2\cos(x)\sin(x))dx\\&=\int\cos^2(x)(2\cos(x)\sin(x))\left(\frac{du}{-2\cos(x)\sin(x)}\right)\\&=\int\cos^2(x)\\&=\int udu\end{aligned}$$

And is thus quite solvable. However, the computer said that this substitution was not correct.

SECOND ATTEMPT:

I used $\cos^2(x) = \frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}$ to get:

$$\begin{aligned}\int\cos^2(x)\sin(2x)dx\\&=\int \left(\frac{1+\cos(2x)}2\right)\sin(2x)dx\\&=\int \left(\frac{\sin(2x)+\sin(2x)\cos(2x)}2\right)dx\\&=\int\left(\frac{sin(2x)}2+\frac{\sin(2x)\cos(2x)}2\right)dx\end{aligned}$$

which is quite a simplification, and we can even take this one further with realizing that since $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ we have that $\sin(4x)=2\sin(2x)\cos(2x)$. Thus our integral becomes:

$$=\int\left(\frac{\sin(2x)}2+\frac{\sin(4x)}2\right)dx$$

which I think is quite simple. However, the homework program did not accept this substitution as the correct substitution to make either.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It can be hard to know what computer tests expect you to type when, because of trigonometric identities, there are multiple ways to write either a useful substitution or the result. If we're looking for a "trig substitution" that's not also a "$u$ substitution", maybe we just want $\sin 2x=2\sin x\cos x$.

Comment: Tried this one :-(. I know, the question doesn't seem well defined does it?

Comment: If they did want a $u$-substitution, the simpler the better: try $u=\cos x$.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest will be to put
$$u=\cos(2x)$$
with

$$\cos^2(x)=\frac{1+\cos(2x)}2$$
and

$$du=-2\sin(2x)dx$$

the integral becomes

$$\int\frac{1+u}2\left(-\frac{du}2\right)=\frac{-1}4\left(u+\frac{u^2}2\right)$$

Comment: The question was just asking for only what trig substitution makes it a simpler integral. We tried this substitution and it said we were wrong :-(.

Answer (score 2):

Use correct substitution in your FIRST ATTEMPT which makes it the simplest as follows 
$$\int \cos^2(x)\sin(2x)\ dx=\int 2\cos^3(x)\sin(x)\ dx$$
Let $\cos (x)=t\implies -\sin(x)dx=dt$ 
$$=-2\int t^3dt$$

Comment: Yeah, again, the answer only wanted the trig substitution itself. I tried this one and it said we were not correct :-(.